# Ubuntu sound card driver

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, sound-card, linux-device-driver

Where can I search for a sound card driver in Ubuntu?

Should I use `sudo apt-cache search` ???
I don't know which command can I use to find my exactly sound card version in linux?

Comment: What's the problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Run the command (as root):

```
# lspci -v
```

This will list all the PCI devices in your system  One of them will be the sound card:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 01d2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at efffc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

Then you can look it up [here](http://hardware4linux.info/search/) to see if it's in the supported hardware list.